# Mongodb concurrent map reduce

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, mapreduce

I have collection with events, indexed by time field. Can i run more then one **incremental** (with output merge to another collection) map-reduce job on it in parallel? (for example - on each five minutes)?

Comment: The JS engine is single threaded per shard or `mongod` so even though you could schedule another MR to be run on the same computer I do not believe it will run until the current running MR is completed

Comment: That being said I do think V8 allows for con-currency features required for your question: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2407 that is something I think you will wanna watch

Comment: thx for answer. didn't read docs carefully =(

Comment: @Sammaye best convert that to an answer ;)

Comment: @RemonvanVliet heh for completeness sake ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript engine is single threaded per shard or `mongod` so even though you could schedule another MR to be run on the same computer I do not believe it will run until the current running MR is completed.

That being said I do think V8 allows for the con-currency features required for your question: http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2407 that is something I think you will want to watch.

Answer (score 0):

Since the MongoDB 2.4 version, the V8 JavaScript engine [became the default](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce-concurrency/) and it allows **multiple JavaScript operations** to execute at the same time.

So yes, you can execute several map reduce jobs concurrently in parallel.